# Simple Prometheus counters query

Tags: java, prometheus

I'm trying to achieve something that it seems very simple, but I can't make it work.

Example code:

```
static final Counter requests = Counter.build()
                    .namespace("sniffer")
                    .name("requests_total")
                    .labelNames("device","method","client","path","status")
                    .help("Total Requests.")
                    .register();
public void process(){
    //... some code
    requests.labels(device,httpMethod, client, path, status).inc();
}
```

I need to draw a graph with the total requests over time grouped by client.

So, I have the metric `sniffer_requests_total`, Which is the query that I have to build to achieve the graph I need?

I tried various queries on `/graph` console and I think I would need something like this:

`rate(sniffer_requests_total[1m]) by (client)`  -> But this is an invalid query, because I can't use `by` with `rate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sum by (client)(rate(sniffer_requests_total[1m])`

See [Common query patterns in PromQL](https://www.robustperception.io/common-query-patterns-in-promql/).